# Qwik - How to access URL parameters in routeLoader$()?

Tags: typescript, qwik

I want to access the URL parameters with `useLocation()` in a `routeLoader$()`:

```js
    export const useRouteLoader = routeLoader$(
      (requestEvent: RequestEvent) => {
        const loc = useLocation();
        console.log(loc.params);
        // Other code
      }
    );
```

But it does not work. I want to log the URL params to the console. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `useLocation()` in `routeLoader$()`s, but `routeLoader$` has access to the `RequestEvent` API which includes information about the current HTTP request, including the URL params.

```
export const useRouteLoader = routeLoader$((requestEvent) => {
  console.log(requestEvent.params);
  //Other code
});
```

See more about `routeLoader$()` at [routeLoader$() Qwik City documentation](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/route-loader/).

See what the RequestEvent contains at [RequestEvent Qwik City documentation](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/middleware/#requestevent).